# Publish ASP.NET Web Site with DevExpress references

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, web, devexpress

I have created a website, not a web application and I used a lot of *DevExpress* libraries. Then when I publish the site, required `DLLs` are not included to bin folder and there is no any "*Copy to local*" option in `ASP.NET` WebSite. I tried to convert the site to a `WebApplication`, but is was unsuccessfully due to complexity of the WebSite. So how can I publish this site on another server where *DevExpress* is not installed?

Answer (score 1):

Deploying the necessary DX assemblies to the server's GAC or in the project's Bin folder should be sufficient to run the application. For more details, please refer to the [Deployment](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q311012) section of documentation.

You can use special tool designed for this purpose.Please refer to the [Assembly Deployment Tool](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AssemblyDeploymentTool/CustomDocument17237) help topic to learn more on how to proceed.

I hope this information helps you.

**References:**
[How to include the DevExpress dlls to publish the solution](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q489810)

Answer (score 0):

I just copied all the required DLLs from DevExpress installation location to the bin folder manually and it worked perfectly.